# How force is transmitted in Magnetic field (Quantum mechanically )

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, virtual-particles

According to particle physics , every fundamental force has its force carrier particle. Photon is a force carrier particle of electromagnetic force but

What is the process through which magnetic field applies attractive and replusive force through photons ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220018/how-can-photons-cause-charges-to-attract/220100#220100 for charges

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to explain intuitively. however repulsion is mediated -as you know- momentum throwing between electrons. however attraction must be though differently. if you sum over all virtual photons you end up some Feynman diagram that shows two electrons shooting a photon out so that they are shifted towards each other. the two outgoing photons are actually the same one.( understand it quantum mechanically). in this way - and + s attract and - and - s or + with +s repulse( a more deep explanation of this is the Pauli exclusion principle. therefore - electrons or + anti electrons try not to be in the same position.)