# What is it about the mechanism for the strong force which creates a force?

Tags: particle-physics, strong-force

So as I understand it, the mechanism for the strong force is that quarks emit/exchange gluons. Similarly, quark-anti-quark pairs are what pass between nucleons in an atom causing them to stick to each other.

But how does this cause quarks, protons and neutrons to stick? What is it about the exchange which creates the strong force?

Comment: How do protons and electrons stick by emitting photons to each other?

Comment: @electronpusher This is indeed a valid generalization of the question: "How do mediating particles induce a force?" And I think it is a reasonable question.

Comment: My answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220018/how-can-photons-cause-charges-to-attract/220100#220100  to the question "How can photons cause charges to attract?" can be extended to the strong interaction exchange forces,   to the question "How can photons cause charges to attract?" can be extended to the strong interaction exchange forces, the boomerang analogy as an intuitive tool.